# Difference between redefining and overriding a function

Tags: c++, c++11, overriding, virtual, virtual-functions

Suppose I have class `A` with a virtual function `F()`:

```
class A
{
    virtual void F()
    {
        // Do something
    };
};
```

And I have another class `B` which inherits `A` and *redefines* `F()`:

```
class B : A
{
    void F()
    {
        // Do something
    };
};
```

And a different class `C` which also inherits `A` but *overrides* `F()`:

```
class C : A
{
    void F() override
    {
        // Do something
    };
};
```

What is the difference between `F()` in classes `B` and `C`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Both `B::f()` and `C::f()` are overrides and they are *exactly* the same.

`override` is essentially a compile-time advisory term that will cause a compilation error *if* the function does *not* override one in a base class.

This can help program stability: if the name and parameter types to `A::f()` are changed, then a compile error will result.

Answer (score 29):

Both are overrides.

When  you use the keyword `override` you ensure a compilation failure if it should happen to *not* be an override.

And that's good practice.

Comment: Not to mention the readability factor when perusing repositories like git

Comment: @Tgsmith61591: Yes. I also wondered whether to include an example of how to overload (essentially "redefine") without overriding. But I decided to be concise. :)